# How to find how many times last value in the inner list are duplicated in a nested list of python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, duplicates

I had a list:

```
a = [[0, 2, 5, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9], [2, 4, 12], [3, 8, 9], [4, 5, 7]]
```

And I want to get `2` because `a[0][-1] == a[2][-1], a[1][-1] == a[3][-1]`

Two of the last value are duplicated.

I tried to use `sum(1 for sublist in a if sublist[-1] == sublist[-1])`
it failed and I got stuck for this.

Comment: What do you mean by last value? 2 is not the last value

Comment: Two times duplicated so I want to get 2

Comment: what is desired output if a = [[0,2,1], [0,3,1], [0,4,1]]?

Comment: To @New2Python, my desire output is 1 because only 1 appear in the last value

Answer (score 2):

You could use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences of the last items:

```
from collections import Counter
last = Counter([i[-1] for i in a])
# Counter({7: 1, 9: 2, 12: 2})
```

And then  count how many of these are greater than `1`:

```
sum(1 for k,v in last.items() if v>1)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of last values from the list, and then count the length:

```
len(a) - len({x[-1] for x in a})
# 2
```

Comment: See my comment @anishtain4.

Comment: @PaulPanzer yeah. It depends on what OP is looking for. `[1,2,1,3,1]` could have an answer of 1 or 2. If `1`, then it's a count of values that appear more than once; if `2` then how many values are actually duplicated.

Comment: Ok, after reading it two more times I agree it  is unclear what is meant.

Comment: this is wrong answer as it returns 2 for a = [[0,2,1], [0,3,1], [0,4,1]]

Answer (score 0):

Since the place of the duplicates does not matter, the problem is simply length of the list minus the unique values. So:

```
last_elements=[i[-1] for i in a]
num_duplicates=len(last_elements)-len(set(last_elements)
```

Comment: What if `last_elements` is `[1,2,1,3,1]`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer It still produces 2 as there's only two duplicates. OP does not say that he wants to check duplicates in subsequent elements.

Comment: They say _"Two of the last value are duplicated."_  which to me sounds like the number of nonunique last values.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Not sure what you mean? Do you mean to say the nonuniques are 3, not 2? Because this won't apply to the OPs example.

Comment: No, I meant 1 is duplicated, 2 is not duplicated, 3 is not duplicated, so there is one duplicated value. But, after reading OP again I'm not so sure anymore. I think your interpretation is just as valid as mine. OP alone knows.

Comment: @PaulPanzer aha, I see now.